# Code casing question for private class fields

Tags: c#

To sum it up, there are two basic trains of thought:

- The private field should just be [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) to match the .NET guidelines
- The private field should be CamelCase but with a _ pre-appended to tell the difference between method scope variables and class scope variables.

## Original Post

Take the following example

```
public class Class1{

    public string Prop1{
        get {return m_Prop1;}
        set {m_Prop1 = value; }
    }
    private string m_Prop1; // This is standard private property variable name.

    // How do we cap this variable name? While the compiler can figure out same casing
    // it makes it hard to read.
    private Class2 Class2;

    // We camel case the parameter.
    public Class1(Class2 class2){
      this.Class2 = class2;
    }
}
```

Here are my stock rules

- The class name is capitalized (Class1)
- The public properties are capitalized (Prop1)
- The private field tied to a public property has `m_` to indicate this. My coworker prefers `_`. There is some debate if using `m_` or `_` should be used at all, as it is like [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).
- Private class fields are capitalized.

The part I am trying to figure out is what do I do if when the class name of a private field matches the private field name. For example, *private Class2 Class2;*. This is confusing.

If the private field name is not the same class, for example *private string Name;*, there isn't much issue.

Or am I thinking about the issue in the wrong way? Should my classes and private fields be named in such a way that they don't collide?

===

The consensus below is to use lower case private property names, but then we have this issue.

```
class1{
    private string name; // This is scoped to the class.

    public void Set(){
      string firstName; // This is scoped to the method.
      .... // Lot of code.
      // Should use this.name but nothing prevents.
      // Now there is confusion if name is a class property or scoped to the method.
      name = firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or ReSharper's guidelines.

Private properties, are cased like any other property.
Private fields, are lower case, starting with an underscore.

```
    private string _foo = string.Empty;
    private string Bar { get; set; }
```

Comment: This seems the best solution as it distinguishes the private class property versus a local method variable, and also solves the problem of the property class being the same as the name.

Answer (score 11):

You should just follow Microsoft's [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx).

And remember to run code-analysis to make sure that you have done it right.

Comment: For public stuff, agreed, because anything else will surprise people. For private stuff, do what your team thinks is best, not what Microsoft thinks is best.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Fair point, but I don't think there is a need to come up with a new convention, when a well thought-through convention already exists, and that can be checked (with CA) automatically.

Comment: To add to T.J. Crowder's point - the Microsoft's naming guidelines cover public interface to classes/interfaces etc... they do not dictate how private members should be named and some of the contributors to the naming guidelines do use _"privatefield" for their own code. This however should be defined and kept consistent for your own team

Answer (score 4):

I would say don't use `m_` or `_` to prefix private fields and name your fields better, if it is named better it would not collide by default.

Comment: +1 for naming your fields better. As someone else reading this code, if I saw private Class2 Class2; I would be pissed. Come up with a name that describes the purpose of the variable.

Comment: Thats the core problem. What if I have a class named Shipment and then the private instance is ? Shipment shipment? Shipment aShipment? Shipment myShipment? etc

Comment: @user200295 it will not just be a shipment but a specific shipment, like an `orderShipment`

_a_ and _my_ does not add any information to the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your issue would be solved if you stick to the coding conventions of the .NET Framework. For example, private members start with lower case.

Comment: The hassle is when a private member shadows a public property, e.g. `name` and `Name`. IntelliSense can *really* catch you out, including introducing endless loops because you missed that it decided you were assigning to the property...in the property setter. :-) I don't care for the underscore convention, but it does help with that sort of problem.

Comment: I also like to lower case method variables, so then there would be confusion when I am using a private class property versus a method variable.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you should follow the Framework Desing Guidelines.
But nevertheless I'm curious why you differ in your naming convention between "private field tied to a public property" and "private class fields"

---

concerning the updated version of your question:
if your method is so long that you are not able to distinguish if a variable was decleared in the method body or as a paramter, than you should think about refractoring....
This is the best answer to this problem that I have heard so far, it is not the best one though.

Comment: I was thinking to indicate the difference between a private field with no public access and a private field with a public property getter/setter.

Comment: concerning the updated version of your question: The best answer I heard once is: "if your method is so long that you are not able to distinguish if a variable was decleared in the method body or as a paramter, than you should think about refractoring." Well it is not the best answer though

Comment: I agree completely, but that still seems suspect. I am leaning towards _camelCase for private properties

Answer (score 0):

They should be named in a way that they do not collide, IMHO